# Why many of Tailwind classes not working in my React App?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I want to use Tailwind css in my React app. I have followed the documentation [Tailwind installation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) and configured my React app to use Tailwind css. However, only some of the classes are working.
For example for background colour `bg-gray-400` is working but `bg-gray-900` will not work and will simply give white background. This is happening for several classes where most of the clsses are not working. I don't know why is it happening so.

Comment: Can you check if class is present in output.css, if it is there add that file to App.tsx

Comment: did you made tailwind.config.js file?

Comment: @JunaidShaikh Yes, I have tailwind.config.js file.

Comment: @SachinJagtap where is that output.css. Only App.css and index.css are present.

Comment: @enggPS you must have used this cmd with tailwind: npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch ?